# Ansible 'NoneType' object is not iterable" error when during a json_query

Tags: ansible, json-query

I have the following code in my Ansible 2.9  to basically display the output of another ansible task that creates VMs and order that output into a readable format:

```
- name: VM creation ouput
  debug:
    msg: "{{ result.stdout | from_json | json_query(jmesquery)  | sort(attribute='VM') }}"
  vars:
    jmesquery: "[].{VM: ResultName, CreatedSuccessfully: ErrorInfo.IsSuccess, PercentCompleted: Progress, CreationTimeCompleted: ReadableEndTime.DateTime}"
```

This works fine if I'm just creating more than 1 (eg: 2) VMs.
However, when I create just 1 VM, the ansible fails with the following error:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ result.stdout | from_json | json_query(jmesquery) | sort(attribute='VM') }}): 'NoneType' object is not iterable"
}
```

Can anyone shed a light on why the json_query would work against the output of more than 2 VMs - but not against just the one? And what can be changed in the code above to make it successful in both cases?

Update (thanks for the tip!), here is the stdout (defined as `result.stdout`):

```yaml
    "stdout": {
        "ErrorInfo": {
            "CSMMessageString": "Error Code : Success ; Message :  ; Recommended Action : ",
            "CloudProblem": "",
            "Code": 0,
            "DetailedCode": 0,
            "DetailedErrorCode": "",
            "DetailedSource": 0,
            "DisplayableErrorCode": 0,
            "ErrorCodeString": "0",
            "ErrorType": 0,
            "Exception": null,
            "ExceptionDetails": "",
            "Formatter": {},
            "GetMessageFormatterHandler": null,
            "IsConditionallyTerminating": false,
            "IsDeploymentBlocker": false,
            "IsMomAlert": false,
            "IsSuccess": true,
            "IsTerminating": false,
            "MessageParameters": {},
            "MomAlertSeverity": 0,
            "Problem": "",
            "RecommendedAction": "",
            "RecommendedActionCLI": "",
            "ShowDetailedError": false
        },
        "Progress": "100%",
        "ReadableEndTime": {
            "DateTime": "Monday, June 8, 2020 10:24:02 AM",
            "DisplayHint": 2,
            "value": "/Date(1591575842677)/"
        },
        "ResultName": "MyVM"
    }
```

Update: I tried the suggestion by Vladimir (thanks so much) and changed my code as below :

```
- name: VM creation details
  debug:
    msg: "{{ result.stdout | from_json | json_query(jmesquery) }}"
  vars:
    jmesquery: "{VM: ResultName,
                     CreatedSuccessfully: ErrorInfo.IsSuccess,
                     PercentCompleted: Progress,
                     CreationTimeCompleted: ReadableEndTime.DateTime}"
  when: stdout is mapping
  ignore_errors: true

- name: VM creation details
  debug:
    msg: "{{ result.stdout | from_json | json_query(jmesquery) }}"
  vars:
    jmesquery: "[].{VM: ResultName,
                        CreatedSuccessfully: ErrorInfo.IsSuccess,
                        PercentCompleted: Progress,
                        CreationTimeCompleted: ReadableEndTime.DateTime}"
  when: stdout is not mapping
  ignore_errors: true
```

However this is failing with an error :

```
TASK [createvm : VM creation details] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /test/server.yml:41
skipping: [myserver] => {}

TASK [createvm : VM creation details] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /test/server.yml:52
fatal: [myserver]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value ({u'msg': u'{{ result.stdout | from_json | json_query(jmesquery) }}'}), and could not be converted to an dict.The error was: No JSON object could be decoded\n\nThe error appears to be in '/test/server': line 52, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: VM creation details\n  ^ here\n"
}
...ignoring
```

Any idea what else I could be doing wrong..?

Thanks!
J

Comment: Update the question with `result.stdout`. Make it [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use test [mapping](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/templates/#mapping) to select the correct query for a dictionary and a list. For example,

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ stdout|json_query(jmesquery) }}"
      vars:
        jmesquery: "{VM: ResultName,
                     CreatedSuccessfully: ErrorInfo.IsSuccess,
                     PercentCompleted: Progress,
                     CreationTimeCompleted: ReadableEndTime.DateTime}"
      when: stdout is mapping

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ stdout|json_query(jmesquery) }}"
      vars:
        jmesquery: "[].{VM: ResultName,
                        CreatedSuccessfully: ErrorInfo.IsSuccess,
                        PercentCompleted: Progress,
                        CreationTimeCompleted: ReadableEndTime.DateTime}"
      when: stdout is not mapping
```

---

Next option is to use the filter [type_debug](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#debugging-filters) that shows the type of a variable. For example, in this case

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ stdout|type_debug }}"
```

gives

```
    "msg": "dict"
```

Comment: HI Vladimir, thanks so much for your input. I have tried your suggestion but ran into a different error..updated my question with this. Appreciate your help and time.

Comment: Looking into this again I found that the stdout was changed due to some changes on the powershell modules that we were calling. Fixed that and now this works :) Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error because you're piping an empty result to the `sort` filter, which expects a list.  You're getting an empty result from your `json_query` expression because you're starting with with `[]`, which refers to a list, but `result.stdout` is a dictionary, not a list.  The following produces a valid result:

```
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ result.stdout | from_json | json_query(jmesquery) }}"
      vars:
        jmesquery: "{VM: ResultName, CreatedSuccessfully: ErrorInfo.IsSuccess, PercentCompleted: Progress, CreationTimeCompleted: ReadableEndTime.DateTime}"
```

Using the sample data you've provided in your question, this produces:

```
TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "CreatedSuccessfully": true,
        "CreationTimeCompleted": "Monday, June 8, 2020 10:24:02 AM",
        "PercentCompleted": "100%",
        "VM": "MyVM"
    }
}
```

There's nothing to `sort` here because the result is a single item, not a list.

Comment: Hi Larsk, I did try this but get the following error `fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value ({u'msg': u'{{ result.stdout | from_json | json_query(jmesquery) }}'}), and could not be converted to an dict.The error was: No JSON object could be decoded\n\`